# What are the advantages and disadvantages of elevons?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, flight-controls

I'm in as student, I wanted to know the advantages and disadvantages of elevons?

Answer (score 6):

[image][Image source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevon#/media/File%3AElevon_(F-102A).svg)

The advantage is: if there is limited real estate available for flight control surfaces, you don't have to divide it up into elevators and ailerons and only use half the available surface for pitch or roll.

The disadvantage is: you cannot go past the surface stop, and there will be situations where a combined pitch and roll cannot be commanded fully by the elevons because one of the surfaces will run into its stop. Resulting in smaller roll & pitch responses than commanded, in only certain situations.